# The generalized Pareto parameters are estimated by MCMC

Tags: parameters, mcmc

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt


class GeneralizedPareto(pm.Continuous):
    def __init__(self, mu, sigma, nu, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GeneralizedPareto, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mu = mu 
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.nu = nu

    def logp(self, value):
        mu = self.mu
        sigma = self.sigma
        nu = self.nu
        
        # 广义帕累托分布 log-likelihood
        logp = tt.log(1 + nu * (value - mu) / sigma)  
        logp -= (1 + 1 / nu) * tt.log(1 + (value - mu) / sigma)
        
        return logp
        
    
# Load the data
data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/chuan/Desktop/HXdata/Rw_S.xlsx")

# Assign data to variables
Rw = data["Rw"].values
S = data["S"].values

# Compute the threshold
threshold = np.percentile(S, 90)

# Filter the rows where 'S' is greater than the threshold
idx = S > threshold
Rw = Rw[idx]
S = S[idx]

# Subtract the threshold from 'S'
S = S - threshold

with pm.Model() as model_gpd:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha_mu0 = pm.Normal("alpha_mu0", mu=0, sigma=10**1)
    alpha_mu1 = pm.Normal("alpha_mu1", mu=0, sigma=10**1)
    alpha_phi0 = pm.Normal("alpha_phi0", mu=0, sigma=10**1)
    alpha_phi1 = pm.Normal("alpha_phi1", mu=0, sigma=10**1)
    alpha_xi0 = pm.Uniform("alpha_xi0", lower=-1.0, upper=1.0)

    epsilon_mu = pm.Normal("epsilon_mu", mu=0, sigma=1, shape=Rw.shape[0])
    epsilon_phi = pm.Normal("epsilon_phi", mu=0, sigma=1, shape=Rw.shape[0])
    epsilon_xi = pm.Normal("epsilon_xi", mu=0, sigma=1, shape=Rw.shape[0])

    # Model specification
    mu = alpha_mu0 + alpha_mu1 * Rw + epsilon_mu
    sigma = alpha_phi0 + alpha_phi1 * Rw + epsilon_phi
    xi = alpha_xi0 + epsilon_xi

    # GPD Likelihood
    pareto_like = pm.Pareto("pareto", alpha=1/xi, m=mu, observed=S)
    
    # draw 5000 posterior samples
    trace_gpd = pm.sample(5000, step=pm.Metropolis())

pm.traceplot(trace_gpd)
```

I try various prior distributions, and try to find a good starting point with find_MAP optimization, and then sample a loosely defined prior based on this point, the same error will be reported, but the value will change:SamplingError: Initial evaluation of model at starting point failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):

File d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\chuan\desktop\hxdata\code\untitled1.py:72
trace_gpd = pm.sample(5000, step=pm.Metropolis())

File d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\sampling.py:428 in sample
check_start_vals(model.test_point, model)

File d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\util.py:237 in check_start_vals
raise SamplingError(

SamplingError: Initial evaluation of model at starting point failed!
Starting values:
{'alpha_mu0': array(0.), 'alpha_mu1': array(0.), 'alpha_phi0': array(0.), 'alpha_phi1': array(0.), 'alpha_xi0_interval__': array(0.), 'epsilon_mu': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 'epsilon_phi': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 'epsilon_xi': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}

Initial evaluation results:
alpha_mu0                -3.22
alpha_mu1                -3.22
alpha_phi0               -3.22
alpha_phi1               -3.22
alpha_xi0_interval__     -1.39
epsilon_mu             -276.60
epsilon_phi            -276.60
epsilon_xi             -276.60
pareto                    -inf
Name: Log-probability of test_point, dtype: float64